# Гласная в суффиксах глаголов первого и второго спряжений.

Tags: глаголы

Я ученица 10 класса.На этом форуме нашла правильное написание слова "движимый" и правило.Нашла,что слово это от глагола "ДВИЖИТЬ",но педагог сказал,что это неверно. Объясните пожалуйста, очень нужно.

Comment: По моему мнению, слово "движимый" образуется от "двигать". Первый раз слышу о глаголе "движить".

Comment: Я тоже не знаю такого глагола,но как тогда объяснить "и" в суффиксе?

Comment: Был раньше глагол **движити**. Думаю, что дело в нем. Источник: Словарь русского языка XVIII в.

Comment: От глагола двигать - причастие  "двигаемый", а "движимый" от устаревшего "движити". Интересно, а как объяснила учительница?

Comment: Она сказала,что это исключение, но я такого в правилах не нашла.

Answer (score 3):

У Розенталя "Справочник по правописанию и литературной правке для работников печати":

В страдательных причастиях настоящего времени пишется: а) суффикс -ем- у глаголов I спряжения, например: колеблемый, проверяемый; б) суффикс -им- у глаголов II спряжения, например: видимый, слышимый. Но: движимый (от старого глагола движити).

У Даля: церк. движити или двизати.

Answer (score 0):

В качестве мозгового штурма: у инженеров есть двигатель (мотор) и движитель (например винт корабля).

Comment: Формы движет и двигает имеют различное значение: Можно сказать: «им движет алчность», но нельзя сказать «двигает алчность».   В русском языке существует ряд глаголов , у которых  усекаемые формы имеют внутренний (активный) характер, а неусекаемые – внешний (пассивный),  например: Любовь, что движет солнце и светила. Но: Скрытный человек не так активно двигает (чем?) пальцами. Также: фонтан  брызжет, но "вздрогнувшие ивы брызгают (чем?) росой".Поэтому двигатель - внешнее устройство, приводящее машину в движение , а движитель - непосредственная (внутренняя) причина движения, рабочий элемент.

Answer (score 0):

Глагол  скорее  всего  один,  и  значение  одно,  здесь  чередование  Г  и  Ж  перед  разными  гласными.  Использование  обеих  форм  в  паре  двигатель -  движитель  с  разным  значением   применяется  в  основном  в  технических  текстах.